# Example of a finite-dimensional vector space, with an example of finite-dimensional subspace and a counterexample

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Give an example of a real finite-dimensional vector space in which give an example of a subspace of dimension $ 3 $ and an example of a subset that is not a subspace. Justify your answers.
$\textbf{Solution}$ An example is $\mathbb{R}$, a finite-dimensional vector space of dimension $n$, $\mathbb{R^{n}}$.
A subspace of dimension $ 3 $ is $ \mathbb {R ^ 3} $. 
We check that $\mathbb{R^3}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$. We know that $\mathbb{R^3} \neq \emptyset$ because $(0,0,0) \in \mathbb{R^3}$, for any $(x,y,z),(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R^3}$, $(x,y,z)-(a,b,c)=(x-a,y-b,z-c) \in \mathbb{R^3}$ and for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}$, $\alpha(x,y,z)=(\alpha x,\alpha y,\alpha z) \in \mathbb{R^3}$.
Therefore, $\mathbb{R^3}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$. 
An example of a set that isn't is $A={(1,0,0,...,0),(0,1,0,...,0),...,(0,0,...,2))}$.
Is my response correct?

Comment: I think by "size" you mean "dimension" (probably just a translation issue). You've proved that $\Bbb R^3$ is a vector space—but is it actually a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$? Is an ordered triple an element of $\Bbb R^n$? Perhaps you need to take a close cousin of $\Bbb R^3$ instead. Your second answer seems correct—indeed any nonempty subset of a vector space that doesn't contain the zero vector is not a subspace.

Comment: Thank you for this observation!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $V= \mathbb{R^3} $ , then $V$ is a finite dimensional linear space over $\mathbb{R}$

Then, $V$ itself an example of a subspace of dimension $3$ of $V$.

Choose any $2$ - dimensional plane or line in $ \mathbb{R^3} $ that doesn't passes through the origin to produce an example of a set that is not a subspace.

There are plenty of others, just try to construct a subset of $         
\mathbb{R^3} $ that is not closed under linear combination of vectors in it.

Comment: Thank you very much!